# Trigger function when property value change of array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, underscore.js

Following is a sample of my object array.

```
$scope.arr = [{"A":"a","B":"b"},{"A":"c","B":"d"},{"A":"e","B":"f"},{"A":"g","B":"h"}];
```

Now I want trigger a function whenever property "A" value changes. Basically to get the count of "A" with a **not empty** value. Following are the sample scenarios need to trigger.

- If value of "A" changed for a newly added object to the array.
- If object removed where property "A" contains a value.
- If value added to empty "A" in a object
- If existing value emptied of "A" in a object

I have gone through Angular watch documentation and it is a possible solution. But my problem is how to watch for the **specific property("A")** in **any object** of array.

Appreciate any help for this.

If no possible solution in Angular, is there any alternative solution with underscore.js ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `$watch`.

e.g.:

```
$scope.$watch("arr",function (newVal,oldVal){
     angular.forEach(newVal,function (val,index){
         if(oldVal.indexOf(val)== -1){
                 //your code
              }
        }) 

},true);
```

Here third argument '`true`' is for deep checking.

Comment: yes but this will trigger if some other value change in the array. In my example this will trigger even if any change in the property "B".

Comment: If same character change which exist in the whole array, this will not work. However this operation is highly cost. So I will look into alternative way to get the count rather than using $watch. Thanks for the support @Ved

Comment: Please update once you done. I will also check for better solution on my free time

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS, there's the `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("arr",function (newVal,oldVal){
    console.log("value has changed from "+oldVal+" to "+newVal);
},true);
```

But this is super expensive.

For vanilla Javascript, here's a non-standard implementation called `object.watch` borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583)

```
/*
 * object.watch polyfill
 *
 * 2012-04-03
 *
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public Domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 */

// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop, handler) {
            var
              oldval = this[prop]
            , newval = oldval
            , getter = function () {
                return newval;
            }
            , setter = function (val) {
                oldval = newval;
                return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
            }
            ;

            if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                      get: getter
                    , set: setter
                    , enumerable: true
                    , configurable: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop) {
            var val = this[prop];
            delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
            this[prop] = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Dustin. Although this (object.watch) cannot be used in my scenario (production environment).

Comment: Yes. But its a costly operation as you said. Going to look for a alternative rather than $watch. Thanks for the support @Dustin